# How to decide how many non-isomorphic unlabeled trees there are?

Tags: graph-theory, trees

As a part of my first course in graph theory, we are to decide how many non-isomorphic  unlabeled trees of order 18 there are. I am not sure how to proceed with this without brute forcing my way and drawing all the 18 non-isomorphic trees. How can I make this problem easier, without having to count all the possible trees?

I am aware of a complicated formula for the number of trees with of order $n$, but I do not think the goal of this assignment is to derive or use the formula, since it involves advanced methods not taught at this level (the generating function for the sequence is well above the level of this course).

Comment: Sounds tough. If you simply [look it up](https://oeis.org/A000055), I think you will discern "brute force" fails miserably. But perhaps the goal is neither to derive nor to use this formula, but instead to do enough fiddling around and hard thinking so that, in the end, you *discover* the formula. So, start at the beginning: Can you do it for order $2$? $3$? $4$? $5$? $6$? etc.? And, as the order increases, can you deduce any patterns to apply as the order increases?

Comment: @LeeMosher I do not think that discovering this formula is within the scope of a *first course in graph theory*.

Comment: @MishaLavrov: Yes, I agree. It's very curious that this was assigned in a first course. It almost sounds like a "whole semester" assignment, i.e a big "end problem" for the course. It makes me wonder how the problem was presented in the course, which is impossible to tell from this post. But still, I wanted to give the OP a point of view on what a mathematician would do when confronted with this problem.